# How to pass values with php from function into an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've read the Q&A regarding this topic, but it unfortunately doesn't answer my question, because I'm a Beginner in PHP.

I'm using a function to display a polygon on a google Map. That works all fine. The coords are stored in the following variable:

```
$polygon = array(
"43.231297 -79.813721",
"43.238438 -79.810768",
"43.230335 -79.809395",
"43.230312 -79.809296",
"43.240208 -79.808983",
"43.230225 -79.808884",
"43.240116 -79.808617",
"43.229823 -79.807388",
"43.231235 -79.802649",
"43.237137 -79.800774",
"43.231297 -79.813721"
);
```

I now want to get the latitude and longitude dynamically out of a MySQL database. My code below runs great and returns the desired coordinates:

```
            <?
                foreach ($BusinessAreaMunich as $item) {
                echo "new google.maps.LatLng(" .$item['AreaCoordLatitude'] . "," .$item['AreaCoordLongitude'] . "), \n";
            }
            ?>
```

However, I've tried to do the following:

```
$polygon = array(
    foreach ($BusinessAreaMunich as $item) {
    echo $item['AreaCoordLatitude'], $item['AreaCoordLongitude'];
}
);
```

Now I know that doesn't work, but I don't know how to solve my issue. Could you please give me an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please learn basic php syntax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Proper code is:

```
$polygon = array();  // define `$polygon` as array
foreach ($BusinessAreaMunich as $item) {
    // create `string` value as a result of concatenating coords and a space
    $coords = $item['AreaCoordLatitude'] . ' ' . $item['AreaCoordLongitude'];

    // append a `string` to `$polygon`
    $polygon[] = $coords;

    // or simply:
    // $polygon[] = $item['AreaCoordLatitude'] . ' ' . $item['AreaCoordLongitude'];
}

// output to see what you have
print_r($polygon);
```

Comment: Perfect, THANK YOU :-)